# Get request body after exception in middleware. .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware

I need to get the request body after exception in my `ExceptionHandlingMiddleware`. Before Exception I get easy request body, but after I can't.
Part of code from `ExceptionHandlingMiddleware` below.

```
    try
    {
      await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
      RequestBody = await FormatRequest(context.Request);
    }

    private async Task<string> FormatRequest(HttpRequest request)
    {
        request.EnableBuffering();

        var body = request.Body;

        var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(request.ContentLength)];

        await request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        var bodyAsText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

        return $"{request.Scheme} {request.Host}{request.Path} {request.QueryString} 
        {bodyAsText}";
    }
```

In result, I get this

[body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sidgt.png)

I tried to get the body in `try` by this way

```
    try
    {
     RequestBody = await FormatRequest(context.Request);
     await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
```

And it works, I get normal `json` data, but I have the exception that my model is not valid because it is empty.

I tried to do `request.EnableBuffering();` before exception but it didn't help me.

So If I try to get body after exception, I can`t parse it. If I get it before exception my model in the controller is not valid.

How I can get my model after exception for logging in `ExceptionHandlingMiddleware`?

Comment: Hi @Stan, could you please share your whole ExceptionHandlingMiddleware? Try to rewind the stream to 0 by using code: `request.Body.Position = 0;`.

Comment: @Rena sorry, it was you. ;) mistake in name in comment. Helped me this `request.Body.Position = 0;` Create the answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually `Request.Body` does not support rewinding, so it can only be read once. A temp workaround is to pull out the body right after the call to `EnableBuffering` and then rewinding the stream to 0 and not disposing it:

```
request.EnableBuffering();

var body = request.Body;

var buffer = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(request.ContentLength)];

await request.Body.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

var bodyAsText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

request.Body.Position = 0;  //rewinding the stream to 0
```